# How can I combine two :not()s?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
:not(h1) > a,
:not(figure) > a {
    background: #859900;
}
```

But it doesn't work, because `figure>a` catches `:not(h1)>a` and `h1>a` catches `:not(figure)>a`. How can I combine those?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Combine the two `:not()` selectors, just as a selector for `.class-a` AND `.class-b` is `.class-a.class-b`.

```css
:not(h1):not(figure) > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1><a>Test</a></h1>
<p><a>Test</a></p>
<figure>
  <a>Test</a>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this, to combine multiple `:not()` selectors:

```css
:not(h1):not(figure) > a {
    background: #859900;
}
```

```html
<h1>
   <a href="http://stackexchange.com">Stack Exchange</a>
</h1>
<figure>
   <a href="http://stackexchange.com">Stack Exchange</a>
</figure>
<h2>
   <a href="http://stackexchange.com">Stack Exchange</a>
</h2>
```